# git command when executed through IIS user does'nt work on server

Tags: c#, git

I have to design an API which will first pull the latest code from the repository and then execute some node js command on that code. I execute this using command prompt through c# code.
Code sample:

```
Process p = new Process();             
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path;  
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";

p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c git pull";
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c node populate";
p.Start();
```

Everything work perfect on my local machine. But when I deployed this on the server only the git pull command not working, rest other commands working perfectly.
Even another git command like - `git status` and `git rev-parse --short HEAD` do work correctly but the problem seems with `git pull`.

I also tried `git pull https://user:pass@domain/repo` but no luck.
When I execute `git pull` command on the server manually through command prompt it works.
If it is due to IIS user permission than what setting are required.

Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your code has `"/c git pull`, is that an error while copying to stackoverflow? I don't think this will even compile since it's not `"/c git pull"`.

Comment: Is there anything logged in Windows Logs? It _could_ (guess, look in logs to verify) be that since `pull` _creates/modifies/delete_ files, that you _do_ have a permissions error. You'll have to give your exe user permissions with `write/modify` in "all" the files/folders that `git` uses.

Comment: Yes it is an error while copying to StackOverflow

Comment: cmd.exe has write permission. when I try creating txt or log file, they are created successfully.

Comment: Can you post the output of the cmd.exe and/or git command execution? If you're not currently capturing this output then this would be your first task, capture the output, then analyze the output, likely it will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Strange is that `git pull` command doesn't even output anything. The statement I made other git commands are working is because other commands output are capture in my log file but the only problem is with `git pull`